# Parsing html timetable code into java

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, timetable

Hy guys, I have ran into trouble. I need to parse timetable from html into java and display it in mobile friendly format. I am going to use jsoup for parsing the html code and I think I will use getElementByTag() to retrieve data. But I am stuck on the algorithm because the html code is all over the place and it looks difficult to be read by jsoup. If anyone has any idea what algorithm to use I would be really happy and you would make my day!

[The link to the timetable](http://timetables.cit.ie:70/reporting/Individual;Student+Set;name;CO.DNET3%0D%0A?weeks=24-31;34-38&days=1-5&periods=1-40&height=100&width=100)

[and also it may look like this](http://timetables.cit.ie:70/reporting/Individual;Student+Set;name;AI.ADCA2-B%0D%0A?weeks=24-31;34-38&days=1-5&periods=1-40&height=100&width=100)

Comment: Looks fine, it's a `table`. jSoup is the right tool. Write some code and when you encounter a concrete issue, come back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but it should work

```
doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(url).get()
css_path = "body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td > table:nth-child(2) > tbody"
tbody = doc.select(css_path).first()
tbody.select("tr") // iterate and process each row as you like
```

You will need to provide var types etc

Comment: This was a really good help appreciate it, and i'm done with sorting the data. [Could you create another path by any chance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558791/css-path-for-jsoup)